# How to hide the delete button in the main body and show it in the next add popup when click on add button using Angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a md-card content in which add and delete buttons are present. I need only the add button to be present when the page is opened. When i click on add button one more md-card will open that must contain both add and delete button. Now everything is working fine as my requirement but i am not getting to hide delete button in the main md-card. Kindly help.

**HTML:**

```
<md-card *ngFor="let positionDetails of positions; let i = index">
                            <div class="clearfix col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <button  (click)="openAddPosition()" > +  </button>
                                <h6 class="color-primary md-headline">Page</h6>
                            </div>
                            <button (click)="deletePosition(row_ind)" style="font-size: 35px;top: -6%; left: 0%;">-</button>
                            <div >
                                <md-input-container>
                                    <input mdInput type="text" name="position" [(ngModel)]="positionDetails.position" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"  required>
                                </md-input-container>
                                <md-input-container>
                                    <input mdInput type="text" name="unit" [(ngModel)]="positionDetails.unit" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required>
                                </md-input-container>
                                <md-input-container>
                                    <input mdInput type="text" name="office_country" [(ngModel)]="positionDetails.office_country" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required>
                                </md-input-container>
                                <md-input-container>
                                    <input mdInput type="text" name="office_city" [(ngModel)]="positionDetails.office_city" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" required>
                                </md-input-container>
                                <md-input-container>
                                    <input mdInput type="text" name="monthly_target" [(ngModel)]="positionDetails.monthly_target" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" >
                                </md-input-container>
                                <md-input-container>
                                    <input mdInput type="text" name="wage" [(ngModel)]="positionDetails.wage" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" >
                                </md-input-container>
                            </div>
                            </md-card>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to hide delete for first/main div, you can check the `index` and if its `0` you can `hide it`

```
<md-card *ngFor="let positionDetails of positions; let i = index">
  ...
  ...
  <button *ngIf="i !== 0" (click)="deletePosition(row_ind)" style="font-size: 35px;top: -6%; left: 0%;">-</button>
</md-card>
```

Comment: thanks for response il chck and update you.. ya trying with update one

Answer (score 0):

**Gist**

What you can do here is check the length of positions and add a class to to your css setting the visiblity to hidden.

**Template**

```
 <button (click)="deletePosition(row_ind)" [ngClass]="{'style1': visibile}"></button>
```

**Component**

check if the length of positions is more if yes then put visible as false else true.

**css**

```
.style1{
  visiblity : hiddden;
}
```

Comment: Component means here deletePosition(index) {
    var item = this.positions[index];
    this.positions.splice(index, 1);
  }  here should i give visible true or false?

Comment: what are you doing on delete removing the element from the array and angular change detection updates the mdcard right , this will check on changes if the length of the positions is == 1 if yes the add the css you can add this in the template too instead of doing this in the component

Comment: so should i add like this?  [ngClass]="{'style1': visibile = false}"

Comment: you can add like `[ngClass]="{'style1': i == 0}"`

Comment: @Bhrungarajni try some thing like `<div [ngClass]= "i == 0? 'style1':'something else'"`

Comment: check if the style is set to that element as this works for me i have just created a project on stackblitz

Comment: ya style is with that element only